# Are Context-Free Grammars with only one Production Rule always Unambiguous?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Consider the following (Context-Free) Grammars with only one production rule (not including the epsilon production):

- $S \rightarrow aSb\;|\;\epsilon$
- $\require{cancel} \cancel{S \rightarrow aSSb\;|\;\epsilon}$
- $S \rightarrow aSbS\;|\;\epsilon$
- $S \rightarrow aSaSb\;|\;\epsilon$
- $S \rightarrow aaSaaSbb\;|\;\epsilon$
- $S \rightarrow aSbScSdSeSf\;|\;\epsilon$
- $\require{cancel} \cancel{S \rightarrow aSSbcSd\;|\;\epsilon}$
- etc...

Are all these Grammars unambiguous? Will every Grammar with only one production rule (not including the epsilon production) *always* be unambiguous? It would seem so, but I'm not totally sure.

> Edit: [Vimal Patel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/101527/vimal-patel) has shown that examples like the 2nd and last are, in fact, ambiguous. Discounting these examples and assuming that the non-terminal symbol $S$ never appears next to itself, does my belief still hold?

Grammars that only contain ***one*** unique terminal symbol could be ambiguous. (ex. $S\rightarrow aSaSa\;|\;\epsilon$) However, Grammars with at least ***two*** distinct terminal symbols seem like they should always be unambiguous.

> Edit II: [Vimal Patel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/101527/vimal-patel) has also shown that production rules which **both** begin and end with the non-terminal $S$ are ambiguous (i.e. $S \rightarrow SaSaSbS\;|\;\epsilon$) discounting this as well, does my belief still hold?

I've tried showing that Grammars like these are $LL(1)$. However, it seems only Grammars of the form  $S \rightarrow aSb\;|\;\epsilon$ are $LL(1)$. Grammars like $S \rightarrow aSaSb\;|\;\epsilon$ are *not* $LL(1)$. (Illustrated in the parse table below.)

[image]

Despite the example Grammar above not being $LL(1)$, it still seems to be unambiguous. Maybe it's simply a matter of using a higher $k$ for $LL(k)$?

In short, are (Context-Free) Grammars with only **one** production rule (not including the epsilon production) and **at least two** unique terminal symbols always unambiguous?

I would really love some help, any at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking something like whether all CFG having only one non-epsilon production which contains two distinct $terminals$  on right hand side of production are always unambiguous? Because all your examples have single $non-terminal$. So they can't have distinct $non-terminal$ on rhs. So you seems to me that you are mistaken in using term $non-terminal$ for term $terminal$.

Comment: whoops! You are correct, I accidentally put non-terminal when I meant terminal. I fixed it. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, your conjecture is wrong.

For instance $S \rightarrow aSSb | \epsilon$ is ambiguous.

To see that take $w: aabb$. For this string we have following two distinct derivation tree possible. In following derivation trees $e$ represents $\epsilon$

```
        S                            S
  /  /    | \                  / /    |    \
a  S      S  b                a S     S     b
 / | \ \   \                    |   / / | \    
a  S  S b   e                   e  a S  S  b
   |  |                              |  |  
   e  e                              e  e
```

---

**Second counter example:**

Consider grammar $S \rightarrow SaSbSaS | \epsilon$
It's easy to see that this grammar is ambiguous. (hint: take $w: abaaba$.)

---

**Third counter example:**

Consider grammar $S \rightarrow abSabSab | \epsilon$.
Take $w = abababababab$. It's easy to see that there are two distinct derivation trees.

Actually this grammar is directly derived from grammar $S \rightarrow aSaSa|\epsilon $ by homomorphism $h(a) = h(ab)$.

Comment: Very good point. In that case, I will ask the same question but discount Grammars wherein the non-terminal symbol S appears next to itself. The question has been updated to reflect your observation.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Another great point. Your second counterexample seems similar to your first (i.e. you can choose between one of two S non-terminals for the production and the other will take the epsilon production). I've updated my question again to reflect your latest observation. I've put some more thought into it and I truly believe that, from here, there shouldn't be any more ambiguities. Thank you again!

Comment: Another excellent point! I was aware that your third counterexample was a possibility but completely forgot to include it as part of my original question. However, I won't add another edit to this post. I think I'll spend some time reformulating my question with these new observations. For now, I'll accept this answer. Thank you so much for your help!