# Are these special (one production) Context-Free Grammars always unambiguous?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, ambiguity

Consider the following (Context-Free) Grammars with only one production rule (not including the epsilon production):

- $S \rightarrow aSb\;|\;\epsilon$
- $S \rightarrow aSbS\;|\;\epsilon$
- $S \rightarrow aSaSb\;|\;\epsilon$
- $S \rightarrow aaSaaSbb\;|\;\epsilon$
- $S \rightarrow aSbScSdSeSf\;|\;\epsilon$
- etc...

Grammars like these uphold 4 basic rules:

1. **The non-terminal symbol $S$ can never appear next to itself.**

   - e.g. $[\;S \rightarrow aSSb\;|\;\epsilon\;]$ would **not** be allowed.
2. **The non-terminal symbol $S$ can appear at the beginning or end of a production but not on both sides at the same time.**

   - e.g. $[\;S \rightarrow SabaS\;|\;\epsilon\;]$ would **not** be allowed.
   - e.g. $[\;S \rightarrow Saba\;|\;\epsilon\;]$ or $[\;S \rightarrow abaS\;|\;\epsilon\;]$ *would* be allowed.
3. <s>**The sequence of terminal symbols that exist between each non-terminal $S$ cannot *all* match.**</s> (EDIT: This rule is redundant, Rule 4 already ensures that at least two sequences of terminals are non-matching)

   - <s>e.g. $[\;S \rightarrow aSaSa\;|\;\epsilon\;]$, $[\;S \rightarrow abSabSab\;|\;\epsilon\;]$, etc. would **not** be allowed.</s>
   - <s>e.g. $[\;S \rightarrow aSaSb\;|\;\epsilon\;]$, $[\;S \rightarrow abSabSaf\;|\;\epsilon\;]$, etc. *would* be allowed.</s>
4. **The sequence of terminal symbols at the beginning and end cannot match.** 
    (i.e. $[\;S \rightarrow ☐_1SaS☐_2\;|\;\epsilon\;]$ s.t. $☐_1 \neq ☐_2$ where $☐_1$ and $☐_2$ are a sequence of terminal symbols)

   - e.g. $[\;S \rightarrow aSbSa\;|\;\epsilon\;]$, $[\;S \rightarrow aaSbSaaS\;|\;\epsilon\;]$, etc. would **not** be allowed.
   - e.g. $[\;S \rightarrow aSbSb\;|\;\epsilon\;]$, $[\;S \rightarrow aaSbSaxS\;|\;\epsilon\;]$, etc. *would* be allowed.

> 5. **The grammar cannot be made to break any of the above rules via a $S \rightarrow \epsilon$ production. ([Vimal Patel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/101527/vimal-patel))**
>
>    - e.g. $[\;S \rightarrow aSbSaSbS\;|\;\epsilon\;]$ could become $[\;S \rightarrow abSabS\;|\;\epsilon\;]$ if the first and third $S \rightarrow \epsilon$, thus violating Rule 4.

Are (Context-Free) Grammars, that follow these 4 rules, always unambiguous? It would seem so. I really don't see any conceivable way that such Grammars could be ambiguous.

(Note: To show why Rule 4 is necessary consider the grammar $S \rightarrow aSbSa\;|\;\epsilon$ with the string $aababaababaa$. A visual derivation can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2erWE.png).)

I've spent a lot of time thinking about this question and have had a hard time finding any way of either proving or disproving it. I've tried showing that Grammars like these are $LL(1)$. However, it seems only Grammars of the form $S \rightarrow aSb\;|\;\epsilon$ are $LL(1)$. Grammars like $S \rightarrow aSaSb\;|\;\epsilon$ are *not* $LL(1)$. Maybe I need to use a higher $k$ for $LL(k)$?

(This question is a follow-up/reformulation [of a previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116312/are-context-free-grammars-with-only-one-production-rule-always-unambiguous).)

I would *really* appreciate any help I could get here.

Comment: If I understand correctly, rules 2 and 3 seem to be redundant (they are implied by rule 4). So, the general form seems to be $S \to \alpha_1 S \alpha_2 S \cdots S \alpha_n | \epsilon$, with the constraints that $\alpha_1 \ne \alpha_n$ and $\alpha_i \ne \epsilon$ for all $i$, where each $\alpha_i$ is a non-empty sequence of terminals.  I'm not sure if I'm missing something...

Comment: I think @meci is trying to convey something else. As per me general form is as follow: $S \rightarrow \alpha_1 S \alpha_2 S ... S \alpha_n | \epsilon$, where $\text{for some i, j } \alpha_i \ne \alpha_j$ and $\text{atmost one Of the }\alpha_1, \alpha_n \text{ can be null }$ and $\alpha_j \ne \epsilon \text{ if } j \ne 1 \text{ and } j\ne n$.  And additionally $\alpha_1 \ne \alpha_n$.  At mecci please verify it if possible.

Comment: Yes! Vimal is correct with his interpretation, that is the proper form.

Comment: @D.W. it does seem that Rule 3 is redundant if Rule 4 ensures that at least two sequences of terminals are non-matching.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the correction.  (Since it is required that $\alpha_1 \ne \alpha_n$, there is no need to add the additional requirement that for some $i,j$ we have $\alpha_i \ne \alpha_j$; that is redundant, as we can simply take $i=1$, $j=n$.)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple counter example:
$S \rightarrow aSbSaSbS \space |\space  \epsilon$

and string $w: abababab.$ 
In one case we use last $S$ and in other case we use second $S$. All other $S$ goes to $\epsilon$.

---

Why I was able to get this grammar?

Let's rewrite above grammar with numbers assigned to each $S$'s.

$S \rightarrow aS_1bS_2aS_3bS_4 | \epsilon$

Now We can virtually eliminate $S_1$ and $S_3$. (For this whenever we have to derive something from $S_1$ or $S_3$ we will only derive $\epsilon$ from both of this type of $S$'s.)

So we get $S \rightarrow abS_2abS_4|\epsilon$.  (At this time we already have got rid of rule 3.)

Which we were looking for.

Comment: Ahh! I see what you did here. By "canceling out" $S_1$ and $S_3$ you have effectively violated Rule 3 without explicitly doing so. Very interesting! Are there any counterexamples that don't "pseudo-violate" these rules?

Comment: I will surely try to find them. And if I succeed then will post them.

Comment: Thank you so much!